# How do get wordpress user ID by meta value?

Tags: wordpress

**There is one:**

```
<?php //...................

$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@example.com' );
echo $user->ID; /* User id */

?>
```

But this, working on `wp_users` table.

> user_login, user_email, user_nicename

I am need work special meta key and value.

> user_phone

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* delete login on user_login 
    if ( ! empty( $username ) )
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

    if ( isset( $user->user_login, $user ) )
        $username = $user->user_email;
*/
/* add login with user_phone  (in wp_user_meta) */
    if ( ! empty( $username ) )
        $user = reset( get_users(
                              array(
                               'meta_key' => 'user_phone',
                               'meta_value' => $username,
                               'number' => 1,
                               'count_total' => false
                          ) ) );

    if ( isset( $user->user_login, $user ) )
        $username = $user->user_email;
/* /end/ add PHONE */

/* Add user login with user_email (in wp_users) */

    $user = get_user_by('email', $username);
```

Well done :)